# Программно задать стиль дочерним элементам XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, ui

Есть `Grid x:Name="MyGrid"` с разными вложенными элементами, среди которых есть пара-тройка `TextBlock`. Никак не могу разобраться, как в некотором событии назначить стиль всем дочерним `TextBlock`. Нужно что-то вроде

```
MyGrid.Children.Select<TextBlock>.Style = Resources["SomeStyle"] as Style;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно именно из code-behind и только непосредственные потомки? Тогда так:

```
var style = (Style)Resources["SomeStyle"];
foreach (var textblock in MyGrid.Children.OfType<TextBlock>())
    textblock.Style = style;
```

---

Обновление: Если нужно обойти все уровни вложенности, используем рекурсию:

```
public static IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> GetDescendants(FrameworkElement fe)
{
    yield return fe;
    foreach (var descendant in
                    LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(fe)
                                     .OfType<FrameworkElement>()
                                     .SelectMany(GetDescendants))
        yield return descendant;
}
```

и потом

```
foreach (var textblock in GetDescendants(MyGrid).OfType<TextBlock>())
    textblock.Style = style;
```

---

Дополнение: В обычных случаях можно установить внутри `Grid`'а стиль по умолчанию через XAML:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource SomeStyle}"/>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Но в случае `TextBlock`'а это может иметь негативные последствия: ведь `TextBlock`'и неявно используются внутри многих других контролов, и установка стиля подействует на них *всех*. (Тем не менее, попробуйте, может быть, этот путь проще!)

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо!

Comment: Так, а если не все потомки непосредственные? Только рекурсивно?

Comment: @Олег: Тогда немного хитрее. Напишу после обеда.

Comment: @Олег: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Простите, я не очень понял дополнение. У меня такая задача, что `MyGrid` - это контейнер для кнопочек на манер менюшки. `TextBlock` - это подписи к иконкам, и там уже сразу задан стиль по умолчанию. Пользователь может скрыть/уменьшить подписи и/или иконки, чтоб не загораживали экран. Вот такую задачу пытаюсь решить назначением разных стилей. А за обновление спасибо - буду сейчас ковырять в ту сторону.

Comment: @Олег: А, понял, вы назначаете стили **динамически**! Обычно изменение вида делается не так: выставляется только раз статический стиль с триггером, который меняет нужные свойства. А в случае, если подменяются сами стили, да, иначе чем из code-behind сделать сложно.

Comment: Да, там есть проверка условия, если пользователь ушел с главной страницы, или наоборот пришел на нее, то тоже стили заменяются. Поэтому не придумал ничего лучше, чем из code-behind проверять и тут-же подставлять нужный стиль. Там есть событие, отвечающее за это. Да и воздействие на `View` из `ViewModel` по наступлению события вроде как не возбраняется в `MVVM`